# How can I turn a DataRow into an XML string using C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a DataRow with columns col1 and col2.  Each column has a value:  val1 and val2 respectively.  How can I turn this into an xml string using C#?

For the DataRow mentioned above I'd like the following string:

```
<col1>val1</col1><col2>val2</col2>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Put the DataRow into a
>   new DataTable. Then call writeXml on
>   the dataTable.

Technically correct, but I would council against this, largely as you have no control over the XML outputted.

I would loop through the rows of the table and use the System.Linq.XML classes to properly format your XML (or if you're feeling more perverse, try XMLDocument and related classes)